# How can I make a repeated pattern in a css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a css grid of the following pattern

- display 4 elements in a row, then display 2 in row, then 12 (as 4 in row), and last 2 (in a row), then repeat the whole pattern again.
  This is a picture of the first iteration:
  [image]

I'm trying the solution with css grid, was bit stuck
FiddleJS: https://jsfiddle.net/g15nyto6/42/

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  /* grid-auto-rows: 50px; */
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.child {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.child:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  background: cadetblue;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.child:nth-child(5n) {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child-1</div>
  <div class="child">child-2</div>
  <div class="child">child-3</div>
  <div class="child">child-4</div>
  <div class="child">child-5</div>
  <div class="child">child-6</div>
  <div class="child">child-7</div>
  <div class="child">child-8</div>
  <div class="child">child-9</div>
  <div class="child">child-10</div>
  <div class="child">child-11</div>
  <div class="child">child-12</div>
  <div class="child">child-13</div>
  <div class="child">child-14</div>
  <div class="child">child-15</div>
  <div class="child">child-16</div>
  <div class="child">child-17</div>
  <div class="child">child-18</div>
  <div class="child">child-19</div>
  <div class="child">child-20</div>
  <div class="child">child-21</div>
  <div class="child">child-22</div>
  <div class="child">child-23</div>
  <div class="child">child-24</div>
  <div class="child">child-25</div>
  <div class="child">child-26</div>
  <div class="child">child-27</div>
  <div class="child">child-28</div>
  <div class="child">child-29</div>
  <div class="child">child-30</div>
  <div class="child">child-31</div>
  <div class="child">child-32</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is unclear, could you maybe add a picture of your desired result? This seems possible, likelly a bit of math and the css Nth child selector.

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: a good reading for your: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-css-grids-implicit-grid-and-auto-placement-powers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the 5th, 6th, 19th and 20th every 20 children. `:nth-child()` accepts a formula of `an+b` form, in which we need to replace `a` with 20 and `b` with 5/6/19/20:

```css
.child:nth-child(20n + 5),
.child:nth-child(20n + 6),
.child:nth-child(20n + 19),
.child:nth-child(20n + 20) {}
```

Try it:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

for (let i = 0, l = 40 + Math.random() * 40 | 0; i < l; i++) {
  const child = document.createElement('div');
  child.classList.add('child');
  child.textContent = `child-${i + 1}`;
  parent.appendChild(child);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
}

.child {
  background: tomato;
  height: 20px;
}

.child:nth-child(20n + 5),
.child:nth-child(20n + 6),
.child:nth-child(20n + 19),
.child:nth-child(20n + 20) {
  background: cadetblue;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by specifying a grid of 4 columns...

EDIT: the description changed and the image makes what is needed clearer. Here's edited version:

...then noticing that everything is in a single cell unless it is a :nth-child(20n+5), :nth-child(20n+6), :nth-child(20n+19) or :nth-child(20n+20) and for these setting the column span to 2.

Here's a simple snippet with a few more elements added to make certain we are repeating the pattern:

```html
<style>
  .parent {
    display: grid;
    width: 100vw;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
  
  .child:nth-child(20n + 5),
  .child:nth-child(20n + 6),
  .child:nth-child(20n + 19),
  .child:nth-child(20n + 20) {
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
</style>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child-1</div>
  <div class="child">child-2</div>
  <div class="child">child-3</div>
  <div class="child">child-4</div>
  <div class="child">child-5</div>
  <div class="child">child-6</div>
  <div class="child">child-7</div>
  <div class="child">child-8</div>
  <div class="child">child-9</div>
  <div class="child">child-10</div>
  <div class="child">child-11</div>
  <div class="child">child-12</div>
  <div class="child">child-13</div>
  <div class="child">child-14</div>
  <div class="child">child-15</div>
  <div class="child">child-16</div>
  <div class="child">child-17</div>
  <div class="child">child-18</div>
  <div class="child">child-19</div>
  <div class="child">child-20</div>
  <div class="child">child-21</div>
  <div class="child">child-22</div>
  <div class="child">child-23</div>
  <div class="child">child-24</div>
  <div class="child">child-25</div>
  <div class="child">child-26</div>
  <div class="child">child-27</div>
  <div class="child">child-28</div>
  <div class="child">child-29</div>
  <div class="child">child-30</div>
  <div class="child">child-31</div>
  <div class="child">child-32</div>
  <div class="child">child-33</div>
  <div class="child">child-34</div>
  <div class="child">child-35</div>
  <div class="child">child-36</div>
  <div class="child">child-37</div>
  <div class="child">child-38</div>
  <div class="child">child-39</div>
  <div class="child">child-40</div>
  <div class="child">child-41</div>
  <div class="child">child-42</div>

</div>
```

Comment: it doesnt work. I need 4 elements after the first two elements in row

Comment: Ah, the description seems to have changed! Thanks for the image - makes it clearer, I'll edit my answer to show that.

Answer (score 1):

You are both really close to the solution. According to the image the cells that should be wider are the 5th and 6th ones, and then again 14 cells later (12 + the 2 wider ones).

This code will do that:

```
.child:nth-child(14n + 5), .child:nth-child(14n + 6) {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

And this segment from the original code should be removed:

```
.child:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  grid-column: span 2; 
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.child:nth-child(5n) {
  grid-column: span 1; 
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

**Update**
To match the pattern (4->2->12->2->4->2->12->2) mentioned in the comment this code will work:

```
.child:nth-child(20n + 5), .child:nth-child(20n + 6), .child:nth-child(20n + 19), .child:nth-child(20n + 20)  {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Comment: I removed my code and I tested it, it keeps repeating 8 elements after the second two elements in row. It should be 4->2->12->2->4->2->12->2 and so on.

Comment: That is not specified in your question, but I will update my code nevetheless, it's just a multiplier issue.

Comment: I think this will work now...

Comment: I have updated the description after posting the picture of the grid, the last solution doesnt work. using child:nth-child(20n + 19), .child:nth-child(20n + 20) works. Its close, and it helped me understand the multiplier. thanks!